# Unable to deploy simple flask app on ubuntu vps

Tags: ubuntu, vps, flask

I am trying to deploy a simple flask app on an VPS running Ubuntu 20 and LAMP

The app runs fine when I execute it with `flask run` from inside the app folder

However the server log has errors:

```
[Sun Oct 24 14:55:03.464311 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5655] [client 90.198.214.109:59097]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Sun Oct 24 14:55:03.464323 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5655] [client 90.198.214.109:59097]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Sun Oct 24 14:55:03.464363 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5655] [client 90.198.214.109:59097]     from flask import Flask
[Sun Oct 24 14:55:03.464386 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5655] [client 90.198.214.109:59097] ImportError: No module named flask
```

The code and instructions are taken from here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

When going to the server's IP, an error message shows up:

`Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

EDIT:

When I run the code using command `sudo python __init__.py` it gives the error that `cannot import flask from Flask` while using the command `sudo python3 __init__.py` works just fine. It seems like the whichever script invokes the wsgi file is calling using the `python` style of calling which triggers the error of being unable to start the script

Comment: please add your answer as an answer and mark this as accepted! Else we will find this question within until serverfault.com gets out of business ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

Turns out the issue was in wsgi.py and which python directory it invokes (has to specifically be /python3, not /python)

Fixed by changing top line in wsgi file to this

#!/usr/bin/python3.8 from tutorial #!/usr/bin/python